# reactjs dangerouslySetInnerHTML and dynamically adding classes to links

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs and working on a project that is pushing json data to the template.

json structure

```
"description" : "Some text with a <a href=\"/de/datenschutz\">link</a> and another <a href=\"/de/cookie-richtlinie\">link</a>",
```

I propose using the following on the template

```
<p className='paragraph-margin-bottom-10 text--font-size-14 paragraph--justified' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: lang.privacy[0].description }} />
```

but in terms of the output - I would maybe need to append a set of classes to ALL links. What is the best practice for this

so the links render with the following

```
<a class="text--font-size-14 hyperlink-primary" href="#">link</a>
```

Comment: Not a real solution, but could you not give the class to `<a>` elements at all? Instead give your classes to the outter `<p>` and adapt your css accordingly.

Comment: well its bootstrap init

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that many people will not agree with me. You can actually do this. But you shouldn't. It is bad enough that you want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. It is possible to parse html but there are many edge cases that you would need to handle.

Either tell your backend that they should return the links with proper classes or target the links inside the description directly with css.

See some similar question like: Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?
[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

This is how I would do it. I will write the regex later if you run into some problems. I don't have much time to spare right now. Hope it will help. :)

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


const htmlFromApi = 'some html from API'

const attachClassesToLinks = (htmlWithLinks) => {
  // do something special
  return htmlWithLinks
}

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>My Component</h1>
    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: attachClassesToLinks(htmlFromApi) }} />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: well using regex seems more bespoke for something like this

Comment: In the end it depends on your needs. If you can be sure that all links that you will get from the API will not have class atribute for example. Then it will be easy. It will get much harder though if you will need to find out whether the link has class atribute. If the class atribute has any value in it. And so on. :)

Comment: if I were to use a regular expression on this -- how would I go about it -- do a componentDidMount?

Comment: I would probably create function that would parse the html (the variable) that you are using in dangerouslySetInnerHTML. Component does not need to know anything about classess of those links unless you plan to change them using component state or something.

Comment: const attachClassesToLinks = (htmlWithLinks) => { // do something special return htmlWithLinks.replace(/<a/g, '<a class="text--font-size-14 hyperlink-primary"') }

Comment: what do you think - its a bit borky

Comment: Looks good enough. Change `class` to `className` `a` is jsx component. But you have to be sure that all the links that you get from the API don't have className attribute.

Comment: When I do that -- it just spews out raw html - it doesnt get rendered on the fly properly

Comment: I mean what I'm trying to resolve here -- is a clean way of pushing html fragment data from a single tag like description --- then applying any styles to that markup -- so at least everything is malleable on a template level

Comment: I am sorry but no.

Comment: what do you mean?